# Retrieve Value from Pyspark SQL dataframe in Python program

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark.sql in a standalone Python program to run a query on a VERSION 0 of a table stored on Databricks.

I can return a data frame using the following code but can not seem to access the value (which is an int 5 in this case)

```
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

 spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

 table_diff_df = spark.sql("select count(*) as result from (select * from myTableName version as of 0 limit 5)")
      
 logger.console(type(table_diff_df))
 logger.console(table_diff_df[0][0])
 logger.console(type(table_diff_df[0]['result']))          
 logger.console(table_diff_df)
 logger.console("tablediff as str :" + str(table_diff_df))
```

## output 1

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
Column<b'result[0]'>
<class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>
DataFrame[result: bigint]
tablediff as str :DataFrame[result: bigint]
```

By adjusting my query to the following(appending *.collect()*) I have been able to get the value of 5 as required (however I had to remove *Version as of 0*)

```
 table_diff_df = spark.sql("select count(*) as result from (select * from myTableName  limit 5)").collect()
 logger.console(type(table_diff_df))
 logger.console(table_diff_df[0][0])
```

## output 2

```
<class 'list'>
5
```

In my case I **MUST** run the query on the Version 0 table, but when I add that back into my query as shown below I get the following error

```
table_diff_df = spark.sql("select count(*) as result from (select * from myTableName  Version as of 0 limit 5)").collect()
logger.console(table_diff_df[0][0])
```

## output 3

```
Time travel is only supported for Delta tables
```

Is there a simple way to access the value using the Dataframe I have shown in the first code snippet(output1)? and if not how can I get around the problem of *time travel is only supported delta table*. The table that I am querying is a delta table however I believe calling .collect() is converting it directly to a list(output2)?

Comment: I ran your code in a notebook.I'd double check that myTableName is indeed a delta table. Use something like `describe extended myTableName`.

Comment: If your code behaves differently between a Notebook and databricks-connect then open a support ticket. Can you confirm that you're using databricks-connect and the versions of databricks connect and your DBR version on your cluster match